# Explain usort in my project

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi a couple days ago I asked for help for sorting my array. I got a response which work perfectly but I'm not entirely sure how it sorts the array in way it does so it was just wondering if someone could just quickly explain how it does what is does.

Heres what I got sent to sort my array. $times_table is my array I created. I don't understand the $a[3] - $b[3].

```
function sortByRandomNo($a, $b) {
   // return $b[3] - $a[3]; // ***descending ****
     return $a[3] - $b[3]; //****Acsending****
}

usort($times_table, 'sortByRandomNo');
```

Comment: If $times_table is an array of arrays, the usort compares pairs of entries in turn ($a and $b).... and you're comparing the 4th element of each entry to see which is the greater

Comment: Thanks for your reply but whats does the " - " do?

Comment: The `-` is simply a mathematical subtraction.... the return value will be a positive or negative integer (or 0 if both the values are the same)..... a positive integer means that $a[3] is greater than $b[3], a negative integer means that $a[3] is less than $b[3]

Comment: And from the [usort() docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php): `The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`, as @mina.nsami has quoted in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the compare function that is passed as a second parameter to `usort`, if you check the php.net documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php, you see that the `value_compare_func` states that

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

that is may be why if you do `$a[3] - $b[3]` is Ascending and `$b[3] - $a[3]` is Descending.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for be annoying and stupid but does that mean if I had 27, 38, 58 and 82 in my 3rd column in my array. Usort is performing 27 - 38, ?

Comment: usort() compares each pair of values (not necessarily efficiently) so it will do comparisons for all the basic combinations like `27-38`, `27-58`, `27-82`, `38-58`, `38-82`, `58-82` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/sX5Ye).... from the result of each comparison (positive or negative return) it knows which elements should be placed before which other elements in the ordered array

Comment: Thanks alot for help and for being patient.